# In Atlanta (S3E10), what's the inspiration behind the hand eating?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, reference

In the Season 3 finale ([S3E10 Tarrare](https://g.co/kgs/QJU5Gy)), the characters are in Paris and Van takes them to an exclusive dinner where the main dish is a fried hand.

What's the inspiration behind this? Is this something that happened in real life and/or what is the significance of it in this episode?

Comment: The title of the episode "Tarrare" is the name of a Frenchman from the 18th century.